# Update specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I control that only specific columns of a table will be updated?

My method is : create instead of update trigger for these tables and control for update only updatable columns and if updated, non updatable column raise error with an appropriate message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use triggers to achieve that but don't use `INSTEAD OF` trigger. 
You can better use `FOR UPDATE` triggers because you don't have to rewrite the whole update query. You only want to deny not allowed updates. If an action is allowed you don't throw an error so the data will be updates as usual.

Example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CheckUpdate] ON [dbo].[MyTable] FOR UPDATE AS

DECLARE @EXPECTED INT = (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM INSERTED)
DECLARE @ALLOWED INT = (
   SELECT COUNT(0)
   FROM INSERTED i 
   INNER JOIN DELETED d 
   ON i.Id = d.Id
   WHERE i.Name = d.Name -- The readonly column
) 

IF(@EXPECTED <> @ALLOWED) -- True if there are not allowed records to updated
BEGIN
    -- Prevent the record will be updated
    RAISERROR ('Readonly columns cannot be changed',11, 1);
    ROLLBACK
END
--Do nothing in the ELSE because everything seems to be OK
--(the record will be updated)
```

You also can make use of `Stored Procedures` to control the update of certain tables.

Comment: why 'FOR UPDATE' is better than 'INSTEAD OF' ?

Comment: I have changed my answer. It explains why ;)

Comment: I dont want to even administrator Mistakenly update non updatable column from SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: even then the FOR UPDATE trigger is triggered so even in MSSM you cannot change not allowed fields

Comment: do we can control updatable column with permission ?

Comment: what do you mean with 'with permission'?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but my sample trigger will deny every not allowed update. You cannot update 'readonly' columns before you have disabled/deleted the trigger

Comment: do I control with low level method than triggers?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12198/discussion-between-hwcverwe-and-mehdi-lotfi)

Comment: Your trigger fails to enforce the read-onliness when a multi-row update occurs, and some rows have `Name` updated and others do not (at least one row will be returned in your `EXISTS()` check).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are alert. Thanks for your comment I have improved the query :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict updates to your database you typically create stored procedures for updates and inserts and use only store procedures and not table updates to update data.

Comment: I dont want to even administrator Mistakenly update non updatable column from SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @mehdilotfi triggers are also triggered if you use MSSMS so no-one can update non-updatable columns without avoiding the stored procedure. In that case it's more safe to use triggers. to avoid triggers the user has to disable/delete the trigger first.

Comment: disable trigger is with awareness. but may be forget of use Stored procedure for update.